# Trying to create submit script to SGE

Tags: bash, submit, qsub

I'm trying to edit my working bash script to an SGE script in order to submit it as a job to the cluster.

Currently I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Perform fastqc on files in a specified directory.

for ((j=1; j <=17; j++))
do
   directory=/data4/una/batch"$j"/
   files=$""$directory"/*.fastq.gz"
   batch=$"batch_"$j""
   outfile=$""$batch"_submit_script.sh"

     echo "#!/bin/bash">>$outfile;
     echo "# Your job name">>$outfile;
     echo "# -N $batch">>$outfile;
     echo "# The job should be placed into the queue 'all.q'">>$outfile;
     echo "#$ -q all.q">>$outfile;
     echo "# Running in the current working directory">>$outfile;
     echo "#$ -cwd">>$outfile;
     echo "">>$outfile;
     echo "# Export some necessary environment variables">>$outfile;
     echo "#$ -S /bin/bash">>$outfile;
     echo "#$ -v PATH">>$outfile;
     echo "#$ -v LD_LIBRARY_PATH">>$outfile;
     echo "#$ -v PYTHONPATH">>$outfile;
     echo "# Finally, put your command here">>$outfile;
     echo "">>$outfile;
     echo "#$ for i in $files;">>$outfile;
     echo "#$ do;">>$outfile;
     echo "#$ fastqc -f fastq -o /data4/una/test/fastq/$i;">>$outfile;
     echo "#$done">>$outfile;
     echo "">>$outfile;

     qsub $outfile;
done
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Unable to read script file because of error: ERROR! invalid option argument "-f"
```

But

```
fastqc -f fastq -o /data4/una/test/fastq/$i
```

is a totally valid line in my bash script.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if related to the error, but there is an excessive semicolon in `echo "#$ do;">>$outfile;` which should be `echo "#$ do">>$outfile;`. Also, you're missing a whitespace in `echo "#$done">>$outfile;` which should be `echo "#$ done">>$outfile;`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input! It actually was poor formatting for my loop that was causing this error. I didn't need to start those lines with `#$`  at all, so those lines become: 
     `echo "for i in $files;">>$outfile;`
     `echo "do">>$outfile;`
     `echo "  fastqc -f fastq -o /data4/una/test/fastqc $i">>$outfile;`
     `echo "done">>$outfile;`
     `echo "">>$outfile;`

    `qsub $outfile;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually was poor formatting for my loop that was causing this error. I didn't need to start those lines with `#$` at all, so those lines become:

```
echo "for i in $files;">>$outfile; 
echo "do">>$outfile; 
echo " fastqc -f fastq -o /data4/una/test/fastqc $i">>$outfile; 
echo "done">>$outfile; 
echo "">>$outfile; 

qsub $outfile;
```